# Which (R)DBMS support true UTF-8 (four byte chars also)?

Tags: sql, database, utf-8

Mysql supports four byte utf-8 characters as of mysql 5.5, but you need to use charset utf8mb4. Apparently on the document storage side MongoDB also supports just up to 3 byte chars.

Are there any database systems that support full UTF-8 character ranges natively?
I'm having difficult of finding a comprehensive reference, since most will claim they support UTF-8 when it's not fully the case.

*Edit: Just to add, I'm looking for this solution because I'm having issues with fetched data containing chinese or emoji characters. I have a DBAL which accepts UTF-8 in the config but I have to manually alter character sets on certain columns to utf8mb4 (mysql). I'd like to know some alternatives for future projects.*